# Separate two images using a statistical approach

Tags: image-processing, frequency-spectrum, cross-correlation

So I have a fundamental question (for which I can't find a good answer anywhere). Say we have two images (A and B) and their mixed image (C) as follows:

[image]

Now say that I've been given Image (A) and Image (C) or Image (B) and Image (C). What are some algorithmic methods that will allow me to separate Image A from Image C or Image B from Image C. My goal is eventually to take something like Image C and decompose it into Image A and Image B. My idea is that if I am given either Image C and Image A or Image C and Image B, I can easily derive the complement (i.e. given A and C, I can get B or given B and C, I can get A).

Algorithmically, I want to do the following:

1. Detect the points that are similar between Image A and Image C (if Images A and C are given) or Image B and C (if Images B and C are given).
2. Reconstruct Image B (Image B') from Image A and Image C (if Images A and C are given) or reconstruct Image A (Image A') from Image B and Image C (if Images B and C are given).
3. Then iteratively delete the newly constructed Image B' or Image A' (from step 2) from either Image C respectively. The output will either be Image B'' or Image A''.
4. Compare the recovered image (from step 3) with the original image. So the idea is to then compare Image B'' with the original Image B or Image A'' with the original Image A.

I'd appreciate any papers or methods that clearly state the mathematics (or statistical technique) used to solve such problems. A lot of fancy words are thrown around but it's really hard to find a precise and easy-to-understand solution for these.

Comment: Any specificity on how they are mixed? I mean, if they are just added together, then $B = C - A$.

Comment: In case the mixture coefficients are not known, you might gess it by minimizing the residual output entropy. Those ideas are used in ICA

Comment: What is the mixing modeling? Is it uniform all over the image?

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 - They are not added with the same proportion so B = C-A wouldn't work.

Comment: @GideonGenadiKogan - The mixture coefficients are unknown. Can you share a paper or method or code that implements that?

Comment: @Royi - I'm not sure. That's a good question. I wouldn't assume that mixing is uniform all across (might be good as a toy problem) but I don't think in practicality that each intensity per pixel is mixed in the same proportion in the next pixel.

Comment: @SpaceCadet2810, You must provide some model of the mixing, without it, I don't think it will work.

Comment: If $C=\alpha A+\beta B$ and you know $A,C$, you can only retrieve $\beta B$, not $B$.

Comment: And if the compositing is non-linear (f.i. involving gamma precompensation/compensation) the problem gets really hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I assume that the registration problem is not the main question here and it can be solved by simple scaling, upsampling to get the subpixel accuracy, and argmax over the correlation between $B$ and $C$.**

**Following I will refer to the rest of the process.**

Assuming $C$ is a linear combination of $A$ and $B$ $$\alpha A + \beta' B = C'$$
Without loss of generality, let us define $\beta=\frac{\beta'}{\alpha}$ and $C=\frac{C'}{\alpha}$. This leads to $$A + \beta B = C$$
Assuming $C$ and $B$ are known, we can optimize $\beta$ for different functions of $A$.

Similar to ICA (following is from Wikipedia),

> separation of mixed signals gives very good results is based on two
> assumptions and three effects of mixing source signals. Two
> assumptions:
>
> 1. The source signals are independent of each other.
> 2. The values in each source signal have non-Gaussian distributions.

This might be utilized in two directions:

> 1. Minimization of mutual information
> 2. Maximization of non-Gaussianity
>
> The Minimization-of-Mutual information (MMI) family of ICA algorithms
> uses measures like Kullback-Leibler Divergence and maximum entropy.
> The non-Gaussianity family of ICA algorithms, motivated by the central
> limit theorem, uses kurtosis and negentropy.

Therefore, one way to extract $\beta$ is

$$\beta=\underset{\beta}{\mathrm{argmax}}\space \mathrm{Kurt}\left[C-\beta B\right]$$

Wikipedia lists numerous other ways to do it...

Comment: None of the three images have the same scale, this won't work without proper registration.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I agree. Will refer to it in my answer

Comment: The registration problem is critical, as it adds four degrees of freedom, making the problem much less tractable.

Comment: @GideonGenadiKogan - this is great! I will try implementing this and share my results. Quick question - can you explain the loss of generality? For example, once I compute $\beta$, I'm assuming that I still need to go back and compute $\beta'$ and and $\alpha$?

Comment: @SpaceCadet2810 you can not get $\alpha$. Say you have a mixture of two images but before the mixing you scale both of them with same scale. Can you restore the scale? I think you can not as it is arbitrary... What the answer missing ro be accepted?

Comment: @GideonGenadiKogan - I understand. You've answered my main concern so I will accept your answer. Thank you!